# How can I show Settings Activity with not back button in Toolbar

Tags: android, settings, vpn

Machine: Lenovo TAB5 801LV

Android OS : 9.0

I tried this Code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_VPN_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
```

after execute this code, show OS VPN Settings Activity.
There is no problem so far.
This VPN Settings Activity has buck button in ToolBar.
this buck button clicked, move OS Settings Screen.

I want to know the way startActivity to VPN_Setting with not buck button in ToolBar or this buck button go to BackTask Activity.

Comment: why u add a new_task flag ?  plz try remove this flag.

Comment: Thanks @cowboi-peng
I remove this setflag  Code and try it. but VPN Setting Activity ToolBar back button action to move OS Setting Screen.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have known, I think you can't remove the back button from they Actionbar in settings app.

But I think you can add

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

to back directly to your app not the OS Settings Screen.